# Optimized structure for normalization of multi value attribute

Tags: sql, sqlite, database-normalization

Suppose I have a table  in which I have a column which is multi-valued, these values are primary key of another table, now I could normalize this by making it single-valued column and repeating the same row for each value that occurs to be in the column, but I guess this is so redundant, note that this column can have up to 100 values(which are foreign key derived from another table).
Now if I make it single-valued column then obviously my rows will be multiplied by the number of keys I take from the foreign table, what is the best practice to normalize this kind of scenario in the most optimized way?

Table-1(
pk,
column-1,
column-2)

Table-2(
pk,
column-1,
column-2,
FK(Table-1))

Here my FK can relate to more than one item of table-1

Comment: Hi. You are just asking for us to rewrite a textbook with a bespoke tutorial. Also you tagged this with "database normalization" so you at least know a term that is relevant that you can research. Please see [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts re research & see hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & show the steps of your work following a published academic textbook (dozens are free online in pdf) & explain about the first place you are stuck. PS There is no point in worrying about vague terms or notions just because you heard rumours about them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)